# Axis labels and ticks in degree, plot in radian

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I've got a plot - the x axis is in radian (from pi/2 to pi) and with gnuplot it works like a charm - the problem is - that my x-axis labeling should be in degree (-90, -75,...,90) and i'm kinda stuck.

Should i change everything to degree or is there an option to achieve this with altering the ticks?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[plot/.style={very thick,raw gnuplot,mark=none,black}]
 \begin{axis}[minor y tick num=3, minor x tick num=1, width=\textwidth, domain=-pi/2:pi/2,
 ymin=0, ymax=1.3, xmin=-1.571, xmax=1.571, grid=both, y=5cm, axis y line=left, axis x line=bottom]
 \addplot gnuplot [plot,red]
     { ag1(x) = 0.5 + 0.2*sin(10*x);plot[-pi/2:pi/2]ag1(x)};
 \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

It should look similar to this picture:
[image]

Comment: Adding, `ytick={0,0.25,...,2},yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{deg(pi*\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}}` does something but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: I don't know where to add that - I tried it but
´! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@yticklabel ...tick )}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]´ was the result.

Comment: Added a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @oerpli: Do you have a particular reason for using gnuplot? (Because PGF uses degrees by default, so that wide sidestep the problem)

Comment: @oerpli You add it to the end of axis options after `bottom` word

Comment: I've read it's more precise and faster.
Also i've already written the plots (there are 16 - each of them is polynom with 7 coefficients) in gnuplot.

Comment: @percusse still results in an errormessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `gnuplot` to use degrees for angles with `set angles degrees;`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[plot/.style={very thick,raw gnuplot,mark=none,black}]
 \begin{axis}[
    minor y tick num=3,
    minor x tick num=1, 
    width=\textwidth,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.3,
    grid=both, y=5cm,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom
 ]
 \addplot gnuplot [plot,red] {
   set angles degrees;
   ag1(x) = 0.5 + 0.2*sin(10*x);
   plot [-90:90] ag1(x)
 };
 \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can convert your result to degrees using an `x filter`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[plot/.style={very thick,raw gnuplot,mark=none,black}]
 \begin{axis}[
    minor y tick num=3,
    minor x tick num=1, 
    width=\textwidth,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.3,
    grid=both, y=5cm,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom,
    x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1*360/(2*pi)}
 ]
 \addplot gnuplot [plot,red] {
   ag1(x) = 0.5 + 0.2*sin(10*x);
   plot [-pi/2:pi/2] ag1(x)
 };
 \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: haha, thanks. that was way easier than i expected.
missed the forest for the trees.